How to run Diskover with docker-compose?
I am trying to run Diskover using docker compose. I tried the Docker compose file from here, but that did not connect to the elastic search engine. I tried to update the docker compose file, but it still does not work.
services:
  diskover:
    image: lscr.io/linuxserver/diskover
    container_name: diskover
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - TZ=America/New_York
      - ES_HOST=elasticsearch
      - ES_PORT=9200
    volumes:
      - /path/to/diskover/config:/config
      - /home/:/data
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    mem_limit: 4096m
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch:8.8.0
    container_name: elasticsearch
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9300:9300
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - xpack.security.enabled=false

This runs Diskover 2.2.2 and the frontend opens, I was able to change the password. But then I get this error:

Attaching to diskover, elasticsearch-1
diskover         | [migrations] started
diskover         | [migrations] 01-nginx-site-confs-default: skipped
diskover         | [migrations] done
diskover         | ───────────────────────────────────────
diskover         | 
diskover         |       ██╗     ███████╗██╗ ██████╗
diskover         |       ██║     ██╔════╝██║██╔═══██╗
diskover         |       ██║     ███████╗██║██║   ██║
diskover         |       ██║     ╚════██║██║██║   ██║
diskover         |       ███████╗███████║██║╚██████╔╝
diskover         |       ╚══════╝╚══════╝╚═╝ ╚═════╝
diskover         | 
diskover         |    Brought to you by linuxserver.io
diskover         | ───────────────────────────────────────
diskover         | 
diskover         | To support LSIO projects visit:
diskover         | https://www.linuxserver.io/donate/
diskover         | 
diskover         | ───────────────────────────────────────
diskover         | GID/UID
diskover         | ───────────────────────────────────────
diskover         | 
diskover         | User UID:    1000
diskover         | User GID:    1000
diskover         | ───────────────────────────────────────
diskover         | 
diskover         | using keys found in /config/keys
diskover         | cp: cannot stat '/app/diskover-web/public/*.sample': No such file or directory
diskover         | [custom-init] No custom files found, skipping...
diskover         | [ls.io-init] done.

Then there are a lot of info messages from the Elasticsearch container, but nothing that looks like an error. I can also reach it via localhost:9200.

I think that diskover service don't support DNS. So, you can try calling via the host' IP.
EX: ES_HOST=IP_of_host

Setting this to localhost:9200 then?

I tried it with ES_HOST=localhost, but I am getting essentially the same error, just with elasticsearch replaced with localhost.

You cannot use localhost but must use IP. You can get the host's IP with ifconfig command (for linux).

Same error when I use the hosts IP address.

Can you share image of error?

Is already shared.
